# python mysqldb query with where

Tags: python, mysql

I use MySQLDB to query some data from database, when use like in sql, I am confused about sql sentence.

As I use like, so I construct below sql which can get correct result.

```
cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE b like %s limit 0,10", ("%"+"ccc"+"%",))
```

Now I want to make column b as variable as below. it will get none

```
cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE %s like %s limit 0,10", ("b", "%"+"ccc"+"%"))
```

I searached many website but not get result. I am a bit dizzy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the second query does not work is that the query that results from the substitution in the parameterised query looks like this:

```
select a from table where 'b' like '%ccc%' limit 0,10
```

`'b'` does not refer to a table, but to the static string `'b'`. If you instead passed the string `abcccba` into the query you'd get a query that selects all rows:

```
cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE %s like %s limit 0,10", ("abcccba", "%"+"ccc"+"%"))
```

generates query:

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE 'abcccba' like '%ccc%' limit 0,10
```

From this you should now be able to see why the second query returns an empty result set: the string `b` is not like `%ccc%`, so no rows will be returned.

Therefore you can not set values for table or column names using parameterised queries, you must use normal Python string subtitution:

```
cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE {} like %s limit 0,10".format('b'), ("abcccba", "%"+"ccc"+"%"))
```

which will generate and execute the query:

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE b like '%ccc%' limit 0,10
```

Answer (score 1):

In the db-api, parameters are for values only, not for columns or other parts of the query. You'll need to insert that using normal string substitution.

```
column = 'b'
query = "SELECT a FROM table WHERE {} like %s limit 0,10".format(column)
cur.execute(query, ("%"+"ccc"+"%",))
```

You could make this a bit nicer by using `format` in the parameters too:

```
cur.execute(query, ("%{}%".format("ccc",))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to rewrite your variable substitution from

```
cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE b like %s limit 0,10", ("%"+"ccc"+"%"))
```

to

```
cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE b like %s limit 0,10", ("%"+"ccc"+"%",))
```

Note the trailing comma which adds a last empty element, which makes sure the tuple that states variables is longer than 1 element. In this example the string concatenation isn't even necessary, this code says:

```
cur.execute("SELECT a FROM table WHERE b like %s limit 0,10", ("%ccc%",))
```

Comment: Thanks for remind, actually, I have a typo in post, I will update it. it is not related with trailing comma.